# Deciding whether series containing $a_n$ are convergent knowing that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}{a_n}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

We know the following thing about sequence ${a_n}$:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}{a_n}=1$$

And now the problem asks us whether it's true for every such $a_n$ that:

1. $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$ is convergent
2. $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ is convergent
3. $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}$ is absolutely convergent

So even though the upper statement looks like we should do something with limit comparison test, I think we cannot do that as we know  that $a_n > 0$ is not true for every such $a_n$. Intuitevely all of these points should be true but what should I use in order to prove that?

Comment: For 1. consider $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1n$

Comment: @robjohn: That's a cute example :)  I request you to kindly provide a rigorous proof for the divergence of this series because we can't simply use linearity like $\sum {{(-1)^n \over \sqrt n}+{1/n}}=\sum{(-1)^n \over \sqrt n}+\sum{1\over n} $ because one of them is divergent and the other is convergent .

Comment: @SrinivasK: Yes you can. Suppose the sum of a convergent series and a divergent series were convergent. Then, by subtraction, we would have a difference of two convergent series that diverges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**$\boldsymbol{1.}$ is false:**

Let
$$
a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1n\tag{1}
$$
Because $\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}$ *monotonically decreases* to $0$, the [Alternating Series Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) says
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\text{ converges}\tag{2}
$$
Because $\dfrac1n$ monotonically decreases to $0$ and $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges, the [Integral Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) says
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\text{ diverges}\tag{3}
$$
Therefore, since the sum of a convergent series and a divergent series diverges,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\text{ diverges}\tag{4}
$$
However,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}{a_n}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}}\\[4pt]
&=1\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

---

There are some claims that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ should converge by the Alternating Series Test.

Although
$$
|a_n|=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{(-1)^n}n\tag{6}
$$
tends to $0$, it does not do so *monotonically*. To see this, note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}
&=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}}\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\\
&\le\frac1{2n^{3/2}}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for positive odd $n$
$$
\begin{align}
&\left[\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{(-1)^n}n\right]-\left[\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right]\\
&=\left[\frac1{\sqrt{n}}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\right]-\left[\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}\right]\\
&\le\frac1{2n^{3/2}}-\frac1n\\[12pt]
&\lt0\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the terms increase from odd $n$ to even $n+1$.

Here is a plot of $\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{(-1)^n}n$ showing the non-monotonicity:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

---

**$\boldsymbol{2.}$ and $\boldsymbol{3.}$ are true:**

Since
$$
\left|\frac{a_n}n\right|\sim\frac1{n^{3/2}}\tag{9}
$$
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}n$ converges absolutely by comparison to $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{3/2}}$ .